# ¿Por qué no puedo copiar los datos de un nodo a otro? JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de copiar una lista a otra, si pudieran darme una mano, se los agradecería.

```
public class Nodo {
    int dato;
    Nodo siguiente;   
}

public class ElementoLista {
    Nodo inicio = new Nodo();
        
    public ElementoLista() {
        inicio = null;
    }
}

// ...

    public void inicio() {
       
         Nodo act = inicio;
         Nodo copia = new Nodo();
         copia.siguiente=null;
         copiar(act, copia);
         
    }

    public int copiar(Nodo lista, Nodo acopiar) {
        if (acopiar == null) acopiar = new Nodo();
        if (lista != null) {
           acopiar.dato = lista.dato;
           return copiar(lista.siguiente, acopiar.siguiente);
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

En inicio es una lista de numeros 55->17->88->null, quiero copiar los datos que hay en el nodo original en una auxiliar, espero ser lo bastante claro.

El problema es que solo copia el primer elemento de la lista, los que faltan no los copia, tendrán algún ejemplo o idea que me pueda servir.
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenidx. Te faltó contarnos cuál es el problema con este código

Comment: Realmente copia solo el primer elemento de la lista, no copia los que faltan.

Comment: Esa aclaración y cualquier info que te pidan en las preguntas, se pone en la pregunta, editándola, que la van a ver más fácil. En principio, no se ve en dónde enlazas los nodos de la lista copiada. Copiar va instanciando un nuevo nodo, pero no se ve dónde lo enlazas con el atributo siguiente del nodo anterior.

Comment: De acuerdo, entiendo. Será posible que me puedas dar una idea sobre como enlazarlos? :(

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el método `copiar` y cómo lo llamas recursivamente.

En la primera llamada, que haces desde el método `inicio`, primero creas un `Nodo`, para que luego el método `copiar` lo rellene con el primer nodo de la lista. Esta parte está bien (aunque la simplifico un poco).

```
public void inicio() {
    // Este nodo se rellenará con la copia
    Nodo copia = new Nodo();
    copiar(inicio, copia);
}
```

Al volver del método `copiar` tienes en la variable `copia` el nodo que se acaba de copiar, que es el primero de la lista original.

Pero no tiene enlazados el resto de elementos copiados, ya que aunque los elementos se copian en nodos nuevos, estos no se van enlazando con nada.
Esto se debe a que llamas al método `copia` indicando que guarde el nuevo nodo copiado en `acopiar.siguiente`, que es nulo.

Recuerda que al hacer `new Nodo()`, tanto desde `inicio` como en `copia`, estás llamando al constructor por defecto (ya que no hay ninguno explícito en la clase `Nodo`), y este constructor inicia todos los campos a 0, false, y en el caso de los objetos, a `null`.

```
public int copiar(Nodo lista, Nodo acopiar) {
        if (acopiar == null) acopiar = new Nodo();
        if (lista != null) {
           acopiar.dato = lista.dato;
           // acopiar.siguiente es null (no se enlaza)
           return copiar(lista.siguiente, acopiar.siguiente);
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

El nodo donde se va a copiar el segundo nodo tiene que haber sido enlazado antes de rellenarlo llamando a `copiar` recursivamente.

```
acopiar.dato = lista.dato;
acopiar.siguiente = new Nodo();  // Se crea un nodo y se enlaza al actual
return copiar(lista.siguiente, acopiar.siguiente);  // Se rellena el nodo ya enlazado
```

Pero esto va a causar que se copie un elemento extra siempre, con valor 0, quedando una lista del tipo 55->17->88->0. Para evitar esto, hay que evitar que se enlace un nodo nuevo si no hay nodo siguiente en la lista original.

```
acopiar.dato = lista.dato;
if (lista.siguiente != null) {
    // Solo se crea y enlaza un nodo nuevo
    // cuando vamos a copiar un nodo de la lista original
    acopiar.siguiente = new Nodo();
    return copiar(lista.siguiente, acopiar.siguiente);
}
```

---

Mencionar que el método `copiar` se puede mejorar, ya que no deberías tener que indicar en qué nodo vas a copiar la lista original. Como tampoco es necesario que devuelvas ningún valor, ya que ese 1 que devuelves, no significa nada, ni lo usas desde el método `inicio`. Lo que debería devolver es el primer nodo copiado, con todos los demás ya enlazados. Y además, debería estar en la propia clase `Nodo`, con lo que no haría falta indicar el nodo que se va a copiar, ya que es el que va a ejecutar el método (referencia `this`, que se puede omitir).

```
public class Nodo {

    int dato;
    Nodo siguiente;

    public Nodo copiar() {
        Nodo copia = new Nodo();
        copia.dato = dato;
        if (siguiente != null)
            copia.siguiente = siguiente.copiar();
        return copia;
    }

}
```

Así, el método `inicio` pasaría a llamarse también `copiar`, con un significado distinto, ya que no copia nodos, sino que copia listas, de la clase `ListaEnteros` (antes `ElementoLista`). Además, se puede eliminar el constructor, ya que solo pone a `null` un campo que por defecto ya está inicializado a `null` (quitando la asignación de `new Nodo`).

```
public class ListaEnteros {

    Nodo inicio;

    public ListaEnteros copiar() {
        ElementoLista copia = new ElementoLista();
        if (inicio != null) copia.inicio = inicio.copiar();
        return copia;
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :D

Comment: Si me funcionó  :D